# Puppet Configuration For Enabling CORS in jfryman/nginx module

Tags: nginx, cors, puppet

My current Nginx manifest file looks like:

```
# Nginx Setup
class nginx_install {
    class { 'nginx': }

    # Setup a development server
    nginx::resource::upstream { 'api_server_dev':
        members => [
            'localhost:3000',
        ],
    }

    # Setup a production server
    nginx::resource::upstream { 'api_server_prod':
        members => [
            'localhost:5000',
        ]
    }

    # Virtual host for production
    nginx::resource::vhost { 'api.elanic.in':
        proxy => 'http://api_server_prod/',
    }

    # Virtual host for development
    nginx::resource::location { '/dev':
        proxy => 'http://api_server_dev/',
        vhost => 'api.elanic.in',
    }
}
```

How should I modify this manifest file so that I could enable CORS in nginx server. I know this can be done following this [link](https://michielkalkman.com/snippets/nginx-cors-open-configuration.html). But I would prefer it to be done through puppet manifests file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to enable CORS in just the vhost or for the whole thing? Since the core nginx conf is a concat::fragment object, it might be possible to add this as a fragment on the end

Comment: I am using nginx as a proxy for nodejs server. For enabling CORS in vhost I had to change settings in nodejs server for enabling CORS. Though my problem is resolved for now. For my knowledge I would totally like to enable CORS for the whole thing. I didn't quite understand the fragment part you are talking about, Can you please give an example?